# PDO does not insert after quote

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to avoid SQL injection in my page.

```
// Connect to database server and select database
$connection = new PDO("mysql:dbname=tt8888;host=mysql.tt8888.com", "tt8888", "ttnopassword");
// Quote data to prevent SQL injection
$name = $connection->quote($name);
// Insert now        
$connection->query("INSERT INTO Contact (name, eeeee, llll, mmmmm, iiiii) VALUES ('$name','$eeeee','$llll','$mmmmm','$iiiii');");
```

Without `quote()`, it inserts just fine. And using `print $name;`, the `quote()` part seems work fine. Why is there nothing inserted into database after using `quote()`?

Comment: You're using PDO wrong. You're vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: You need to be using placeholders, not building SQL with untrusted data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`PDO::quote`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) will put single quotes around your values. So you don't need to do that yourself in your SQL.

Though I'd strongly recommend you switch to using [`prepare()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with named parameters.

Comment: Thanks, it works great now! Btw if all I have are strings, is using quote() OK for preventing injection? I tried to use prepare() and the page broke.

Comment: _"I tried to use prepare() and the page broke"_ then you were probably using it wrong. Refactor using named parameters, and post a new question if you have a specific problem getting those to work (or better yet just search, there are tons of answers already floating around).

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `PDO::quote`.  It is much better to use parameterized queries.

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO Contact (name, e, l, m, i) VALUES (?,
    ?, ?, ?, ?)");
// This will quote all of the values for you
$stmt->execute(array($name, $eeeee, $llll, $mmmm, $iiiii));
```

You can also use `bind` methods (`bindParam` or `bindValue`) instead of passing the arguments directly to `execute`.  This will allow you to specify the data types if it's necessary, but it seems like these are all supposed to be strings.

Comment: @LearningClojure turn error reporting on; what is the error you get from that line?

Comment: Now I realize what is going on. It was some small problem. Thank you!